# pdfs: Why some pdf files structure can be viewed in text editor while others only show hex

Tags: pdf

I have two pdf files:

One if i open in the sublime text i see as below: (showing only the partial text)

```
%PDF-1.5
%ÐÔÅØ
10 0 obj
<<
/Length 192       
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
---SOME GARBAGE TEXT HERE
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Form
/FormType 1
/PTEX.FileName (/test.pdf)
/PTEX.PageNumber 1
/PTEX.InfoDict 14 0 R
/BBox [0 254.12001 432 288]
/Group 11 0 R
/Resources <<
/Font << /F1 15 0 R>>
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]
>>
/Length 253
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
-- SOME GARBAGE TEXT HERE
endstream
endobj
18 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length1 28220
/Length 13768
>>
stream
```

`---SOME GARBAGE TEXT HERE` is not shown because it does not get pasted.

Where as other if i open in sublime text i see it as:  (showing only the partial text)

```
2550 4446 2d31 2e35 0a25 d0d4 c5d8 0a34
2030 206f 626a 0a3c 3c0a 2f4c 656e 6774
6820 3138 3920 2020 2020 2020 0a2f 4669
6c74 6572 202f 466c 6174 6544 6563 6f64
650a 3e3e 0a73 7472 6561 6d0a 78da a552
b10a 0231 0cdd fb15 f981 8b69 9ab6 d75d
10dd d451 9c14 5c3c e45c fc7d d33a 5851
84eb 5148 d2e4 bdd7 a464 3416 484f b691
d15a 380d e670 2438 6b62 0384 3625 7814
c800 e208 5d1f 34be c2de 6ccd 5891 bd60
8ad2 ca76 82c1 b791 3b05 16a3 e83f 02e5
8de8 bfe8 5958 5478 8682 38e4 d8cf 50f0
c418 684e 0ff4 fa86 c6df ef24 62e4 4974
bd71 12f8 74f7 0bfc ccef 5686 406b 50f9
89fc 77b3 8429 953d 1b8d 46c1 71a9 5461
2955 c3b1 aea6 e59c 5eac 070b cb9b b6df
30c0 44fc 1325 faab 130a 656e 6473 7472
6561 6d0a 656e 646f 626a 0a31 2030 206f
```

What is the difference between these two types of pdfs.

Is there any way to convert to either formats from each of them.

Comment: pdfs can have text streams in plain text or compressed, but I suspect the hex form you show is your editor choosing to show a binary file as a hex dump rather than really being in that form in the pdf, hard to tell from just a fragment.

Comment: The first few bytes of your hex dump  `2550 4446` are `%PDF`

Comment: looks like sublime text does have a hex viewer so that is what you are seeing: https://superuser.com/questions/946694/sublime-text-opens-an-xml-file-in-hex-view

Comment: Both these files are generated by pdflatex. How to tell pdflatex to produce plain text instead of compressed

Comment: To decompress object streams, try something like `qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable filename.pdf filename-qpdf.pdf`. But I think what's happening here is that both files contain a mixture of ASCII and binary data (what you called "SOME GARBAGE TEXT HERE" in your first sample) and your editor is using a heuristic to decide that if the amount of non-ASCII binary data in a file is higher than a certain threshold, then show the entire file in hex. Try a less "smart" viewer (maybe `less` on the terminal, or Notepad if you're on Windows, or whatever) to confirm.

Comment: No the second file is not as you show, it just has enough non ascii characters that your editor decided to show you it in that form, Try looking at the two files in a different editor to see what I mean. It is purely a question about sublime text viewing options not about the pdftex generation

Comment: to tell pdftex to not compress you can use `\pdfcompresslevel=0 \pdfobjcompresslevel=0 ` but the form you are showing is not PDF it is a hex dump, the second file will start off with the characters `%PDF` it is just your editor showing them as `2550 4446`  as hex 25 is `%`, hex 50 is `P` etc.

Comment: You are right. I again opened using sublime text, it shows %PDF. I was surprised. Then i realized it nothing to do with PDF but sublime text.